# SSL on Nginx throws error (SSL: error:0908F066:PEM routines:get_header_and_data:bad end line)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, ssl, zerossl

I generated my SSL from SSLforFree/ZeroSSL, and according to the steps for installation listed on their website, https://zerossl.com/help/installation/nginx/

1. Downloaded the SSL Files
2. Moved them to the Server
3. Merged the certificate.crt & ca_bundle.crt with (`cat certificate.crt ca_bundle.crt >> certificate.crt`)
4. Added following lines in the hosts file of nginx:
   `ssl    on;`
   `ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/certificate.crt;`
   `ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/private.key;`
5. Restarted Nginx Server with (`sudo service nginx restart`)
6. Error received, and checked the error details by (`journalctl -xe`)
7. Error was:
   `nginx: [emerg] PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX`
   `(SSL: error:0908F066:PEM routines:get_header_and_data:bad end line)`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Merging files with `cat certificate.crt ca_bundle.crt >> certificate.crt`, merges the file without adding any next line character in it.
After merging the files, open the newly created file, i.e, certificate.crt, and you'll see the file structure as follows:
`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`
`certificate-1-text`
`-----END CERTIFICATE----------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`
`certificate-2-text`
`-----END CERTIFICATE-----`

If your certificate looks like this, you can fix this by adding adding a new line character just before 5 hyphens of second begin certificate, i.e, it should look as follows after editing:
`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`
`certificate-1-text`
`-----END CERTIFICATE-----`
`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`
`certificate-2-text`
`-----END CERTIFICATE-----`

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. Just be careful about the number of hypens you need to take to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What went wrong was I had a new line in between the code before the CERTIFICATE-----. I fixed that it all worked fine.
But this helped me troubleshoot. Thanks,